# MariaDB: Before Insert trigger to conditionally abort writing a new record

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I'm attempting to create a trigger to abort writing a new record for a library database if the book in question has already been loaned out. Here's what I have so far:

```
CREATE TRIGGER OnlyOneBorrowerAtATime
BEFORE INSERT ON Transaction
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF (EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM Transaction
       WHERE NEW.bookId = Transaction.bookId AND Transaction.transType = 'Loaned'))
THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
       SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Book has not been returned';
END IF;
END;
```

I get the following error back from MariaDB:
SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 9

MariaDB version is 10.5.9.

Comment: That usually means mismatched parentheses, or missing delimiter but I note that you never changed the delimiter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `DELIMITER` to your query like

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER OnlyOneBorrowerAtATime
BEFORE INSERT ON Transaction
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF (EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM Transaction
       WHERE NEW.bookId = Transaction.bookId AND Transaction.transType = 'Loaned'))
THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
       SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Book has not been returned';
END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: That did it. Thanks!